# Is it possible to screenshot a widgetTest?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, widget-test-flutter

I am new to Flutter and I feel like if I could see what the widgetTest is "rendering", as a debug method, things could be a bit easier.  I don't fully understand at the moment the mechanics of the widgetTest, but I am wondering if it is possible to capture an actual output render in the middle of the widgetTest.

I am talking about widgetTest not integration test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the package [golden_toolkit](https://pub.dev/packages/golden_toolkit) might be what you are looking for. Instead of using `widgetTest` you will be using `testGoldens`. And you can even compare screenshots if you want to ensure non regression in your UI using the provided method `screenMatchesGolden`.

Add in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
#This is a development environment dependency only
dev-dependencies:
  golden_toolkit: ^0.9.0
```

**Code Sample:**

```dart
testGoldens('MyWidget test', (tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidget());
  await screenMatchesGolden(tester, 'my_widget-example');
});
```

Then run the following command to generate or regenerate your reference images:

```sh
flutter test --update-goldens
```

You can check the documentation about `testGoldens` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/golden_toolkit#testgoldens).

Comment: You also need `dart_test.yaml` at your project's root, like this: https://github.com/eBay/flutter_glove_box/blob/master/packages/golden_toolkit/dart_test.yaml